# SpringBoot Crud repository

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-boot, crud

I have a organization class as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "org")
public class Organization implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private long id;
      private String orgname;
```

I am trying to link Org table to from userorg table.
The link between the two is , userorg table references orgid.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_org")
public class UserOrganization implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  private long userid;
  private long orgid;

  @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
  @JoinTable(name="user_organizationList",joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="orgid", referencedColumnName="id")})
  private Organization orgData;
```

The orgData is always null.

Can anyone please help me to establish this join

Comment: try this [How to create join table with JPA annotations -](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979382/how-to-create-join-table-with-jpa-annotations)

Comment: maybe you need inverseJoinColumns?

Comment: @sasanka the examples join with primary key. In my case, I want to join User and Userorg with orgid where orgid is not a primary key in user table

Comment: Following the documentation, maybe you're missing the inverseJoinColmuns part.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html