# JPA @ManyToOne join table issue

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I am working on an authentication model that would suit GlassFish's JDBC Realm requirements.

In this model I have one group which can contain multiple users, but each user can only be in one group (e.g. su, admin, etc.).

I have two entities: Groups.java (for groups) and Credential.java (for users) and intend to feed the generated join table to Glassfish's "Group Table" property.

I am able to persist both Groups and Credential instances, but the required middle table (credential_groups) is not even created, let alone updated.

Below are my entities:

Credential.java:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Table(name = "credential")
public class Credential extends MetaInfo implements Serializable {
private String username;
private String passwd;
private Groups group;
private boolean blocked;
private boolean suspended;

public Credential() {
    super();
}

public Credential(String createdBy) {
    super(Instant.now(), createdBy);
}

public Credential(String createdBy, String username, String passwd) {
    this(createdBy);
    this.username = username;
    this.passwd = passwd;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "username")
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
    updateModified();
}

@Column(name = "passwd")
public String getPasswd() {
    return passwd;
}

public void setPasswd(String passwd) {
    this.passwd = passwd;
    updateModified();
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Groups getGroups() {
    return group;
}

public void setGroups(Groups group) {
    this.group = group;
    group.getCredentials().add(this);
    updateModified();
}

@Column(name = "is_blocked")
public boolean isBlocked() {
    return blocked;
}

public void setBlocked(boolean blocked) {
    this.blocked = blocked;
    updateModified();
}

@Column(name = "is_suspended")
public boolean isSuspended() {
    return suspended;
}

public void setSuspended(boolean suspended) {
    this.suspended = suspended;
    updateModified();
}
}
```

Groups.java:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Table(name = "groups")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "findAllGroups",
            query = "SELECT g FROM Groups g order by g.modifiedDate DESC")
})
public class Groups extends MetaInfo implements Serializable {

private String groupName;
private Set<Credential> credentials;

public Groups() {
    super();
    credentials = new HashSet();
}

public Groups(String groupName) {
    this();
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

public Groups(String createdBy, String groupName) {
    this();
    setCreatedBy(createdBy);
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "group_name")
public String getGroupName() {
    return groupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
    updateModified();
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "groups")
@JoinTable(
        name = "credential_groups",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_name"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username")
)
public Set<Credential> getCredentials() {
    return credentials;
}

public void setCredentials(Set<Credential> credentials) {
    this.credentials = credentials;
}

public void addCredential(Credential c) {
    credentials.add(c);
    if (c.getGroups() != this) {
        c.setGroups(this);
    }
}
}
```

As I said persisting both works (for Groups I have also tried updating, querying), but this error keeps on firing on every operation with either entity:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-4d2_54'
Error Code: 1022
Call: ALTER TABLE credential ADD CONSTRAINT FK_credential_GROUPS_group_name FOREIGN KEY (GROUPS_group_name) REFERENCES groups (group_name)
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="ALTER TABLE credential ADD CONSTRAINT FK_credential_GROUPS_group_name FOREIGN KEY (GROUPS_group_name) REFERENCES groups (group_name)")
```

**Important update:**
This is the error that is being thrown even before the pasted above exception:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (credential, group))' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: CREATE TABLE credential_groups (credential VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, group VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (credential, group))
```

As requested by Francois Motard, here's my jUnit method that triggers the error (the group is created in another test class):

```
public class CredentialRepositoryTests {

private final OCGroupsRepository groupRepo;
private final OCCredentialRepository credentialRepo;

public CredentialRepositoryTests() {
    groupRepo = new OCGroupsRepository();
    credentialRepo = new OCCredentialRepository();
}
...
@Test
    public void createCredentialTest(){
        //retrieve the group
        Groups admin = groupRepo.getByGroupName("admin");
        Credential rimma = new Credential("user_creator", "sample_user", "abc123");
        admin.addCredential(rimma);
        assertTrue(groupRepo.updateGroups(admin));
    }
```

I based my code on the instructions from the EJB 3.0 in Action by Manning and tried to resolve the join table issue based on this stackoverflow answer: [How to create join table with JPA annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979382/how-to-create-join-table-with-jpa-annotations)

Can anyone help me have the join table created and updated? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by removing the `mappedBy` attribute from the `@OneToMany` annotation of the owned entity (this fixed the non-creation of the join table) **and** by adding the `unique` attribute (set to true - this solved the "`PRIMARY KEY (credential, group)`" issue) to the `@JoinColumn` annotation inside the `@JoinTable` of the same property:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "credential_groups",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_name"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username", unique=true)
)
public Set<Credential> getCredentials() {
    return credentials;
}
```

Main take away don't ever ever combine a "mappedBy" with the `@JoinTable` in a ManyToOne/OneToMany entities pair.

Comment: By removing the mappedBy, you disassociate the OneToMany from the ManyToOne.  If this is all you did, they are now separate relationships; the ManyToOne mapping will default to using a foreign key in the credential table which is completely independent of entries in the credential_groups table.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. The 'CredenitalRepository' has a 'List<Credential> getByGroups(String group)' method that passed the test. I didn't print out the returned values, but the returned size was correct.