# JPA Mapping Subscriptions & User Entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a social networking app and a Subscription table/entity and User table/entity. I want to map a many to one relationship from Subscription to User but am not sure how best to capture the relation. Read up on this link on [JPA Relationships](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships)

Here is my code so far [Link to gist code](https://gist.github.com/flyingCodeMonkeys/14351fefbd4d99e40607e969c2a59333)
there seems to be something wrong with my annotations.

I have a User table/entity with a user_id and name. My Subscription table has a subscriber(User) and a publisher(User)
and an embedded composite key.
How do you map the relation and then access the table/entity so I can add or remove subscriptions?

Comment: see this might helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979382/how-to-create-join-table-with-jpa-annotations

Comment: @vinay hegde the problem is i want it almost to be self referential. Like a user can subscribe to as many other users as he wants. And he can have 0 to many other follower (users). Most solutions came across use a join table of 2 separate parent entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ManyToOne and @OneToMany annotations should do the work for you.

Use List in the User class which will contain the subscriptions of each user.

Comment: So in my User class I have a list of subscriptions with a @OneToMany annotation. how do i do the mappings though? 
How can i map the user id with the publisher and subscriber fields?

Comment: You are gonna map the entities in Java. You will use the mappedBy property to specify the field in the other entity to map it with. 
https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

Comment: how do you set the foreign key constraints? I used the OneToMany annotation in my User.subscribers and User.publication. And in my Subscription class I have '''User subscriberID''' and '''User publisherId'''. They are both ManyToOne. i want it to point to the user_id though of User table. See gist

Comment: Map them directly to the field in the User entity.